How to find out which app fills my gallery with images?
Since yesterday my gallery is getting filled with pictures I never asked for. Looking at metadata didn't reveal which app is doing this:

Could you suggest how to fix this?

Possible dupe: Monitor and identify which apps create a specific file/directory (also dupe to self Q&A, needs root access)
